# How to store classes in Laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5

I wish to store classes in my Laravel model.

For example, say I have a model called `M` with an attribute `b`, which takes a class called `Foo`.

I wish to be able to to do something like this.

```
$foo = new Foo();
// ...
$m = new M();
$m->b = $bar;
$m->save();
```

However this gives me a `Object of class Bar could not be converted to string` error.

Furthermore I should be able to do the opposite.

e.g.

```
M::first(5)->b; // Returns the associated `Bar` object who has id 5.
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You should use [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) or [PHP serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php). The former is the way to go in almost all scenarios, including yours apparently.